# Vector Matrix multiplication via ARM NEON

Tags: ios, matrix, vector, arm, neon

I have a task - to multiply big row vector (10 000 elements) via big column-major matrix (10 000 rows, 400 columns). I decided to go with ARM NEON since I'm curious about this technology and would like to learn more about it.

Here's a working example of vector matrix multiplication I wrote:

```
//float* vec_ptr - a pointer to vector
//float* mat_ptr - a pointer to matrix
//float* out_ptr - a pointer to output vector
//int matCols - matrix columns
//int vecRows - vector rows, the same as matrix

for (int i = 0, max_i = matCols; i < max_i; i++) {
    for (int j = 0, max_j = vecRows - 3; j < max_j; j+=4, mat_ptr+=4, vec_ptr+=4) {
        float32x4_t mat_val = vld1q_f32(mat_ptr);    //get 4 elements from matrix
        float32x4_t vec_val = vld1q_f32(vec_ptr);    //get 4 elements from vector

        float32x4_t out_val = vmulq_f32(mat_val, vec_val);  //multiply vectors
        float32_t total_sum = vaddvq_f32(out_val);          //sum elements of vector together
        out_ptr[i] += total_sum;
    }

    vec_ptr = &myVec[0];   //switch ptr back again to zero element
}
```

The problem is that it's taking very long time to compute - 30 ms on iPhone 7+ when my goal is 1 ms or even less if it's possible. Current execution time is understandable since I launch multiplication iteration 400 * (10000 / 4) = 1 000 000 times.

Also, I tried to process 8 elements instead of 4. It seems to help, but numbers still very far from my goal.

I understand that I might make some horrible mistakes since I'm newbie with ARM NEON. And I would be happy if someone can give me some tip how I can optimize my code.

Also - is it worth doing big vector-matrix multiplication via ARM NEON? Does this technology fit well for such purpose?

Comment: Perhaps you need to rethink the algorithm, or use shaders as @Jake mentioned below (I believe that would be [OpenGL](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) or whatever you can use on iOS).

Comment: Would any of the code in the ARM CMSIS DSP library be of help? There are matrix multiplication functions there that use NEON and they don't look anything like yours. It would at least be worth looking at how they do it.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your tip! I will definitely have a look to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is completely flawed: it iterates 16 times assuming both `matCols` and `vecRows` are 4. What's the point of SIMD then?

And the **major** performance problem lies in `float32_t total_sum = vaddvq_f32(out_val);`:
You should never convert a vector to a scalar inside a loop since it causes a pipeline hazard that costs around **15 cycles everytime**.

The solution:

```
    float32x4x4_t myMat;
    float32x2_t myVecLow, myVecHigh;

    myVecLow = vld1_f32(&pVec[0]);
    myVecHigh = vld1_f32(&pVec[2]);
    myMat = vld4q_f32(pMat);

    myMat.val[0] = vmulq_lane_f32(myMat.val[0], myVecLow, 0);
    myMat.val[0] = vmlaq_lane_f32(myMat.val[0], myMat.val[1], myVecLow, 1);
    myMat.val[0] = vmlaq_lane_f32(myMat.val[0], myMat.val[2], myVecHigh, 0);
    myMat.val[0] = vmlaq_lane_f32(myMat.val[0], myMat.val[3], myVecHigh, 1);

    vst1q_f32(pDst, myMat.val[0]);
```

- Compute all the four rows in a single pass
- Do a matrix transpose (rotation) on-the-fly by `vld4`
- Do vector-scalar multiply-accumulate instead of vector-vector multiply and horizontal add that causes the pipeline hazards.

You were asking if SIMD is suitable for matrix operations? A simple "yes" would be a monumental understatement. You don't even need a loop for this.

Comment: Perhaps I understood, but I believe `matCols` is `10000` and `vecRows` is `400`?

Comment: @Groo It's simply not feasible then. Perhaps you need CUDA at that point. We really don't need the classic Fourier Transform since we have FFT, do we?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response! But can you explain what you meant by "it iterates 16 times assuming both matCols and vecRows are 4. What's the point of SIMD then?"

Comment: "You don't even need a loop for this" - do you mean I don't need a loop in my case? Could you elaborate on this as well?

Comment: And I didn't ask if ARM NEON is suitable for Matrix operations. To be specific, I asked if it's worth using it for a big matrices and vectors.

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev The short answer is yes, you can do very large matrix-vector multiplication on NEON. The catch is however, there is no single ideal implementation for any size of problems. Building a car is something very different from building a train. There are other factors about the sizes: Are they two power of n? Are they multiple of four or eight? etc. Note that matrix-vector multiplication is nothing else than matrix height times dot products of the length of vecRows. It's quite an easy task.